# How to copy logging configuration to several Jboss7 servers from a reference server?

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

Is there a way to copy a logging configuration (all tags in standalone.xml that are between  and ) from a given Jboss7 server to another one ? This on order to have exactly the same logging configuration on all servers ?
As standalone.xml is modified dynamically by JBoss7, simply copying the standalone.xml is not possible, as we may have differences in other config subsystem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a [CLI script](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes) to configure logging. You can then run the script with `jboss-cli.sh` (or `.bat` for Windows).

Example logging configuration script:

```
# Start batching commands
batch                                       

# Add the periodic rotating file handlers corresponding to those added to the logging properties file
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE_QS_WARN:add(suffix=".yyyy.MM.dd", file={"path"=>"quickstart.warn.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE_QS_ERROR:add(suffix=".yyyy.MM.dd", file={"path"=>"quickstart.error.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE_QS_INFO:add(suffix=".yyyy.MM.dd", file={"path"=>"quickstart.info.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE_QS_DEBUG:add(suffix=".yyyy.MM.dd", file={"path"=>"quickstart.debug.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE_QS_TRACE:add(suffix=".yyyy.MM.dd", file={"path"=>"quickstart.trace.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE_QS_FATAL:add(suffix=".yyyy.MM.dd", file={"path"=>"quickstart.fatal.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})

# Configure the loggin async handler
/subsystem=logging/async-handler=WARN_QS_ASYNC:add(level=WARN,queue-length=1024,overflow-action=BLOCK,subhandlers=["FILE_QS_WARN"]) 

# Create the logger for our quickstart class, assign the handlers
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:add(level=TRACE)

# Create the logger for our quickstart class, assign the handlers
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:assign-handler(name="WARN_QS_ASYNC")
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:assign-handler(name="FILE_QS_ERROR")
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:assign-handler(name="FILE_QS_INFO") 
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:assign-handler(name="FILE_QS_DEBUG") 
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:assign-handler(name="FILE_QS_TRACE") 
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.quickstarts.logging:assign-handler(name="FILE_QS_FATAL") 

# Run the batch commands
run-batch
```

You then run the script, assuming the name is configure-logging.cli, like so:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --file=configure-logging.cli
```

**NOTE**: There is a bug in JBoss AS 7 with the above script that requires two batches to be run. Just add a run-batch and another batch after adding the logger. Essentially before you add any handlers to the logger.

Comment: i was thinking about that solution, this confirms it ! Thanks a lot